# How to combine a photo and sound file to an video file which is acceptiable on youtube?

Tags: video, audio, youtube

I'd like to combine a photo and some sound file together and upload to youtube, not sure how to do it.

Any suggestion will be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for software suggestions to combine the two? If so, are you on a Mac or PC?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion on windows the free Movie Maker is the best solution for small youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

That's user interface tool, I hope I could find some web API tools, so that my application could call it programmatically.

btw, I found one site: http://www.mediaconverter.org/ do the manual upload.

Any suggestion?